# Intended brightness setting for sRGB?

Tags: display-calibration, monitors, display, srgb

This is more of a general question about whether there is an intended brightness setting for viewing the full sRGB gamut on a screen, but my device specifically is a Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite, and sRGB mode has been enabled in the developer options but there is still a brightness setting. I was wondering if there is a specific brightness for sRGB (I assume to get the most of the gamut, there would be) and if so, is it plausible to know where the intended brightness would be for sRGB? E.g would it be high, low, in the middle, etc? Is there anywhere I could find the intended brightness setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display Calibration For Viewing On Displays / Devices](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85499/display-calibration-for-viewing-on-displays-devices)

Comment: @MichaelC That question talks about ISO viewing conditions but not sRGB, which are different.

Comment: The other question talks about both display conditions and screen brightness. sRGB is no different from any other color space. The ISO specifications apply to display brightness based on the type of technology used to emit light (e.g. CRT, LCD, etc.), regardless of the color space the system uses.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

The "official" sRGB display spec is a peak white is 80 cd/m², with a 2.2 display gamma, per the IEC standard.

## Longer Answer

Needless to say very few people set at 80 nits except at night/when dark.

120 cd/m² is a common reference level. This assumes that the surrounding diffuse reflective field of view of the room is about 24 cd/m² (20% of peak white).

Some people set to 160 cd/m² -- even 220 cd/m². The ambient lighting will dictate a lot of where you want to set your monitor peak white.

Either your contrast/brightness controls or if your monitor has a direct gamma control will probably also need to be adjusted along with its brightness and the ambient light for the same/appropriate perceptual intent.

A brighter display or a darker room, or both, usually results in increasing the display gamma for the same perceptual intent.

A darker display or a brighter environment usually means a need to flatten the gamma, i.e. lowering it.

Assuming you have a good quality hardware display calibrator like an Xrite I1 Display Pro (or whatever they are calling it today, LOL), you can measure your ambient illumination as well as the display—so you can dial all these in to work properly together.

If you don't have a display calibrator, but you have a good spot meter, you can set the display to `#ffffff` and adjust peak white measuring cd/m² with the spot meter.

Comment: Interesting. It would be nice to add some references. :)

Comment: Hi @Rafael references for which? The IEC standard is 61966-2, for the rest, look at Xrite documentation, and also at Basiccolor documentation. I suppose I should publish a more complete article on the subject at some point… is there a specific question you’d like a specific reference for?